# Cassandra JMX need to connect all the nodes

Tags: cassandra, jmx, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

I am trying to get to know Cassandra cfstats information from all the machines using JMX. This can be done using OpsCenter, but I do not want to use it. I started building my own utility. For now, my java program connects to JMX and fetching cfstats information such as estimateKeys, No of SSTables ..etc.

My requirement is, This is a java jar file, will run from one Cassandra node and should be able to connect to all the machines and fetch cfstats using their respective JMX per node.

I am planning to use java driver for this, as java driver will be able to connects all the machines in the cluster using system.peers coumnFamily. Once java driver connect to the machines, I will form the service:jmx:rmi using respective hostname and JMX port(7199). Then I will be able to connect to NodeProbe using this information.

My question is, after connecting to the another node using java driver, will I be able to retain state there and after forming service:jmx:rmi url, will this url really connects to the current node JMX and pull cfstats information from the current node. Because JMX host name it will take from the Cassandra-env.sh file. Can some one please help me in this.

Does this idea works or is there another best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use JMX [remotely](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html), but that's not the easiest thing to do.

But if you are writing your tool - maybe it's worth to check out a different connection. E.g. you can easily convert JMX calls to HTTP using [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/features-nb.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time on this Deniszh. I will check the feasibility and let you know.

Comment: Hi All, Any other ideas on my questions above?